# Windows 8 Certification NDISTest 6.5 LWF logo test fails

Tags: windows-8

I have raised a query regarding the problem which I am facing since 3 weeks. Please find the link below.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/277bbbe3-dbab-4056-acfc-ae1c39ac51c8/ndistest-65-lwf-logo-test-fails-due-to-checkconnectivitystress?forum=whck

Problem Statement :-
Certification of Windows 8 with windows server 2012.
Test Name : NDIS 6.5 LWF Logo Test
Fails : CheckConnectivityStress
Problem : Received less than the expected percentage of packets sent. 
                     The test adapter and support adapter tries to ping each other for a given amount of time and meanwhile the support adapter gets disconnected resulting in the failure of this test.

Regards,
Priyata